# Implementing Long Range Peer To Peer Data Exchange Over IOS

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit, bonjour

I am looking for a solution to be able to send location data between two iPhones.  I looked into Bluetooth data exchange but it is only a 10 meter range.

I have looked at Bonjour, however I haven't seen anything yet that would allow you to broadcast as a server over a 3g network.  Is this possible?

Would I be able to use the Game Center for sharing data that is non game related?

Thanks In Advanced...

Comment: no,you can not use Game Center for sharing data that is non game related.
you need to build a server first

Answer (score 0):

Not true. GameCenter just passes data. It has no concept of whether the data is game date, location data, or whatever.

Also, I dont think you can't use Bonjour to find devices over 3G. I believe you have to use a game center match invitation for devices not on the same local subnet.

If both devices are connected to the same wifi network, you can use Bonjour.